# Cors attribute for origin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors

I have a set of MVC web apps, that call one particular restful API (.net apps across the board).  They are all on the same server, but different apps.  I have added the standard CORS Attribute to my API to allow for the web apps to access the API. `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`.  I really don't like the idea of allowing all (*) traffic.  Can anyone suggest a value that I can put in the Origin attribute with the web apps are as listed below?  Can I do soemthing like this `[EnableCors(origins: "https://MyAwesomeCompanySite*, http://MyAwesomeCompanySite*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` or `[EnableCors(origins: "https://localhost*, http://localhost*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`? Actually, I tried those two examples and they did not work.

Public facing websites:
http://MyAwesomeCompanySite/Administration
https://MyAwesomeCompanySite/PointOfSale
https://MyAwesomeCompanySite/Reporting

API that all the websites utilize:
https://MyAwesomeCompanySite/ThisIsMyAPI

Answer (score 0):

I think `[EnableCors(origins: "https://MyAwesomeCompanySite, http://MyAwesomeCompanySite", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` would work for you.